# wp_oembed_get method only works once?

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields, oembed

I have a page videos.php on wordpress, where I'm getting videos urls from youtube, through custom fields (I'm using the advanced custom fields plugin).
I used the

```
wp_oembed_get()
```

method to get the videos. However, it only works for the first custom field, and i have 8 others. Is this normal? 
How can i work this around?